# Sylius installation aborts

Tags: php, mongodb, symfony, sylius

I want to try out sylius but I have the following problems with installation :

```
php composer.phar create-project sylius/sylius -s dev /wamp/www/sylius2
```

Error message :

```
Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
Warning: The lock file is not up to date with the latest changes in composer.jso
n. You may be getting outdated dependencies. Run update to update them.
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1
- Installation request for doctrine/mongodb 1.0.3 -> satisfiable by doctrine/mongodb[1.0.3].
- doctrine/mongodb 1.0.3 requires ext-mongo >=1.2.12,<1.5-dev -> the requested PHP extension mongo is missing from your system.
Problem 2
- doctrine/mongodb 1.0.3 requires ext-mongo >=1.2.12,<1.5-dev -> the requested PHP extension mongo is missing from your system.
- doctrine/mongodb-odm dev-master requires doctrine/mongodb 1.0.* -> satisfiable by doctrine/mongodb[1.0.3].
- Installation request for doctrine/mongodb-odm dev-master -> satisfiable by doctrine/mongodb-odm[dev-master].
```

After reparing in deifferent ways the request problems, I try to execute :

```
php app/console sylius:install
```

Error message :

```
PHP Warning:  require_once(C:\wamp\www\sylius2\app/bootstrap.php.cache): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\wamp\www\sylius2\app\console on line 15

Warning: require_once(C:\wamp\www\sylius2\app/bootstrap.php.cache): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\wamp\www\sylius2\app\console on line 15

PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required 'C:\wamp\www\sylius2\app/bootstrap.php.cache' (include_path='.;C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.6\pear') in C:\wamp\www\sylius2\app\console on line 15

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'C:\wamp\www\sylius2\app/bootstrap.php.cache' (include_path='.;C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.6\pear') in C:\wamp\www\sylius2\app\console on line 15
```

This seems to be normal because the steps of composer command were interrupted.

So in the first place why do I get those request problemes on mongodb - Is there any way to get this fixed ?

Answer (score 2):

It has been fixed in master. MongoDB is no longer required to run Sylius, unless you want to use it with this storage.

Answer (score 0):

In `composer.json` remove `"doctrine/mongodb-odm":         "1.0.*@dev"` from the `require-dev` section and remove the , (comma) from the previous item. This should remove all dependencies on MongoDB which you don't have installed.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you requested Sylius "[dev](https://github.com/Sylius/Sylius/blob/master/composer.json#L58)" version (*-s dev*) and you don't have "php mongo extension" installed on your system. If you're running Debian distribution it would be as simple as `sudo apt-get install php5-mongo`. Please keep in mind that you need to register mongo extension in your `php.ini` file and for this particular task you have to edit eg `/etc/php5/cli/php.ini` file (note *CLI*). I also suggest you to register your mongo extension in web server configuration also eg `/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini`. Simple add one line `$ echo "extension=mongo.so" >> php.ini` to your `php.ini` file. That'd be all!

If you don't need Sylius "*dev*" stability simply remove **"-s dev"** argument when doing composer create project command:

`php composer.phar create-project sylius/sylius /wamp/www/sylius2`

Hope that helps!

Comment: Hello and thanks for your answers.
Do I really need mongodb for sylius ? Because I would like to use mysql ... Is this possible ?
But my principal problem is that I need to get this create project command work without error so that all steps are executed. 
And as I can't modify composer.json as long as I have not executed create project command (because its created with this command) I can't see any solution right now.

I'm on windows and as I prefer to work with mysql and not with mongo I'm looking for a solution where I do not need to install extensions that will not serve for anything.

Comment: the answer is: no, you don't need mongodb installed on your system... try without **-s dev** argument. `php composer.phar create-project sylius/sylius /wamp/www/sylius2`

Comment: Ok - I just tried without -s dev : php composer.phar create-project sylius/sylius C:\wamp\www\sylius

Now the installation works fine in the beginning but when it comes to flow-bundle ther is this error :

    Installing sylius/flow-bundle (dev-master 68c6dba)
    
    Cloning 68c6dba027a269c9b5e17c385b2e23729983c714
    
    [RuntimeException]
    
    Failed to execute git checkout "68c6dba027a269c9b5e17c385b2e23729983c714" &
    
    & git reset --hard "68c6dba027a269c9b5e17c385b2e23729983c714"
    
    fatal: reference is not a tree: 68c6dba027a269c9b5e17c385b2e23729983c714